# error while opening a database in SQLite in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have made this code to open a database(created in SQLite browser) stored in assets folder in my app:

```
public class DatabasetryActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ArrayList<String> queryString;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
queryString = myDbHelper.getData(new String[] {"Area","disease"}, null, null, null,
"Area"," ASC");
try {

myDbHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

myDbHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

throw sqle;

}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
queryString));   
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

where DatabaseHelper is another class in same package but  while running this android project on emulator the following message appears on console tab:

```
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to
the front
```

and nothing appears on the emulator. please help me out. Thanks
Guys please help me out as this is my first post here..and i am new to android

Comment: Is there a reason you create your DatabaseHelper twice? Also, could you perhaps fix your indentation?

Comment: @Bart there is no particular reason for that. i will take care of indentation in my further questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use to create your data base is actually an SQLiteOpenHelper.  You can find the documentation for it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).  You can also find various questions about it on StackOverflow.  You can then use a list adapter to add database items to a list.  This should simplify your code and make the SDK work for you.  You can Google this and there will be many example.

Also a tip for future posts.  You can add spaced to the code in your questions/answers so the indentations are correct and make it easier to read.  StackOverflow is a great community and will help you learn quickly as a developer.  Welcome and get involved!

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable response.but actually i don't want to create my database in SQLiteOpenHelper instead i want to use the database created in SQLite browser.so i tried to open the databse in DatabaseHelper class but it isn't working..

Comment: @user182022 I would def recommend the SQLiteOpenHelper because it creates a nice way to update the DB in the future and guarantees your DB exists.  But if you don't want to its okay to, you know your situation better.  Look at the link I provide in the onCreate() method you will see how a DB is actually created using the db.exec() command to run and SQLite command.  Use this to create your DB where you need to. http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-creating-a-sqlite-database

Comment: i do understand the benefit of SQLiteOpenHelper class but i want to make an app that is based on database means which displays just my database in one way or other.Should i choose this class then coz my database is large??I have to write a very big code then..isn't it??plz correct me if i m wrong..

Comment: @user182022 The SQLiteOpenHelper is nice because it will control you DB creation and Upgrades in a single location for you.  All you really need to do in implement the onCreate and onUpgrade methods with how to handle creation and upgrade.  But like I said, you don't have to use it, it is just very convenient.